# Formula for z axe in Inverse Kinematics JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, inverse-kinematics

Formula for z axe in Inverse Kinematics JavaScript

For x axe: `x + Math.cos(angle) * segment_length`;

For y axe: `y + Math.sin(angle) * segment_length`;

For z axe: z + ???

Answer (score 0):

If your angle is the angle between a line in the xy plane and the x axis in the xy plane (as it appears), then z is unchanged.

You may want spherical polar coordinates, which involves 2 angles, theta and phi. This wikipedia article explains all: [Spherical Polar Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polar_coordinates).